# Table: Scrollable tbody, fixed tfoot

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a tfoot element in my table structure which I want to stay fixed at the bottom, while the tbody remains scrollable. I have read various related questions and answers, and most seem to utilize ***nested tables***.
While one might argue that "*whatever works is whatever you should use*", using nested tables feels (might be just me) like a dead wrong approach and against the little I have learned about markup. Are there not any more "sane" solutions to use-cases such as this?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these pieces of code according to your needs.

If you need a webpage with footer always on bottom:

```
<body>
    <div style="padding-bottom:60px;">
        <!--main content here-->
    </div>
    <div style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:60px;left:0;bottom:0;">
        <!--footer content here-->
    </div>
</body>
```

If you need a custom block somewhere:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px">
    <div style="padding-bottom:60px;">
        <!--main content here-->
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:60px;left:0;bottom:0;">
        <!--footer content here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Footer height in example is 60px - it can be anything actually. Use CSS file for styles (I wrote inline for better explanation).

Also I **do not recommend to use nested tables**. Yes, you can use a sledge hammer as a nutcracker, but it would not be effective.